# Why was my answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I am puzzled by why a moderator deleted my answer:

[Why is the mean of the natural log of a uniform distribution (between 0 and 1) different from the natural log of 0.5?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/433314/why-is-the-mean-of-the-natural-log-of-a-uniform-distribution-between-0-and-1-d/433359#433359)

Comment: Do you have a specific question about how to write a good answer? I think that the general explanation at https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer provides a general outline: directly answer the question and provide specific reasoning. A rhetorical question might be helpful as a comment, but a rhetorical question on its own is not an Answer to the question.

Comment: You might also be interested in: [How should questions be answered on Cross Validated?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1390/7290)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your answer was flagged by two users as being of low quality. I think it's more of a comment, or a hint, than an answer; & it doesn't seem to add anything to the other answers.

Comment: FWIW, if I were actively moderating, I would have deleted the post, possibly while converting it to a comment.

Comment: OK. This is an answer to my question here so I'll accept it. Obviously I disagree with the opinion on the answer itself, which addresses a fundamental issue masked by the specificity of the question itself. Perhaps too laconically.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the original answer in full:

> Other answers address the question about the natural logarithm directly.
>
> In more generality, why would you expect that for an arbitrary function $f,$ the mean value of $f(x)$ should be $f(0.5)$?

It doesn't answer the question.  Indeed, it's explicitly framed as another question! That's ideal as a Socratic *comment,* but it definitely should not stay up as an answer.

Perhaps that post should have been converted to a comment, another option available at the time.  I would be glad to do that retroactively.

Comment: We disagree, but see my comment on the answer here I accepted.

Comment: What do we disagree about, exactly?  Do you maintain your post answers the question? Do you believe it would not serve as a good comment?  Do you disagree it is framed as a question?  I'm struggling to find any evidence for any of those interpretations.

Answer (score 6):

Why would you expect that the first question in a longer socratic dialogue, is supposed to answer the question?